# Python regular expression with optional beginning and end

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to extract a string from in between two expressions that might or might not be there in every example i.e.:

- a gift **from:** Julius E. Gregovich from apartment 10B **to:** Bruce
  Faulk
- Leon Cross and Mary Williams **to:** Kenneth J. S. Andrews
- **from:** Mary R. Williams

in every one of these I want to extract what's between "from:" and "to:", so:

- Julius E. Gregovich from apartment 10B
- Leon Cross and Mary Williams
- Mary R. Williams

I can't solve the problem of the missing keywords though. What I tried up to this point is an expression that has two alternatives:

```
(?:from:)(.*?)(?=from:)|(.*?)(?=>to:)
```

But I can't work in an alternative where both keywords are present

Comment: Did you mean using 3 capturing groups? `(?:from: (.*?) to:|from: (.*)|to: (.*))` https://regex101.com/r/Gufra1/1

Comment: Is it possible that NEITHER will be there? Should it match everything or nothing in that case?

Comment: You can add a third alternative to your regexp with both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

`(?:.*from: )?(.+?)(?: to:.*|$)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7Tj9Lx/1

Your desired return value will be in the first and only capture group.